# On overview, answers, votes, comments all show as modified

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

On Stack Overflow, when you get an overview of questions for a certain tag, each question has an avatar/flair next to it showing who asked the question, and when.

On CR, though, as soon as someone answers this question, or changes somthing, the *asked* bit disappears from the overview, and instead a *modified* box shows up, showing the last user that *"acted"* upon the question. It could well be an edit, answering or commenting or closing the question (not sure in which cases this behaviour shows), but considering most questions don't show the person who asked the question in the first place, I'd say pretty much all of these actions will have this affect.

Is this expected behaviour, or is it a bug? I'm not sure if this is even desirable, but I'd be happy to adjust my views if I understand the reasoning behind this...

As requested, a screenshot of what I'm on about. I did not ask the top JS question. I answered it, yet next to the title, it shows my flair. As [you can see here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/floating-point-representation-754-format-in-javascript), I did not edit the question in any way, either and still:

[image: modified instead of asked]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where that screenshot is taken from you are on the **Active** list, so it actually shows activity on the Question, so for this purpose it will show who was last active on the question, and that is why it shows **"modified 1 hour ago"**

if you go to another sub-tab like **newest**  it will show you the author of the question.

the **Active** sub-tab is the only one where it shows who was last active on the question